# Polynomial long division using Fourier transform (deconvolution)

Tags: polynomials, convolution, fourier-transform

Multiplication between polynomials $u$ and $v$ can be performed via a convolution between their vectors of coefficients $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$. According to the convolution theorem, the vector of coefficients of the product $\vec{p}$ is obtained by:

$\vec{p} = F^{-1}(F(\vec{u}) \odot F(\vec{v}))$

$F$ denotes the Fourier transform, $F^{-1}$ its inverse, and $\odot$ the component-wise multiplication.

On the other hand, division $q$ between $u$ and $v$, where $u$ has $v$ as a factor ($u = vq$), can be performed using:

$\vec{q} = F^{-1}(F(\vec{u}) / F(\vec{v}))$

However, if $v$ is not factor of $u$ ($u = vq + r$), how can I get the remainder $r$?

Comment: A remark about the division: it cannot be a practical method because $F(\vec{u}) / F(\vec{v})$ needs that **all** components of $F(\vec{v})$ are non zero...

Comment: @JeanMarie You are right, but let us assume that they are nonzero. I am not looking for practicality ;)

Comment: This amounts to using the formula: $$c_n = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint \frac{f(z)dz}{z^{n+1}}$$ for the expansion coefficients of an analytic function, where the contour is a circle around the origin. In this case you apply this to the ratio of the polynomials, the contour needs to avoid the zeros of the denominator.

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes but this problem appears only if you use the discrete Fourier transform (of size $N$). If you use the **discrete time** Fourier transform, that is padding with infinitely many zeros and letting $N  \to \infty$,  you get that the division is well-defined (of course since the DTFT of $(a_n)$ the coefficients $P(x)= \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n x^n$ is just $P(e^{-i \omega t})$)

Comment: Otherwise, I think you can look at the derivatives $\frac{d^m}{d\omega^m} P(e^{-i \omega t})|_{\omega = 2\pi k/N}$ at a zero of the DFT, for making the division by $P(e^{-i \omega t})$ well-defined

Comment: @user1952009 I agree: I recognize that I was thinking to the DFT, not to the continuous Fourier Transform.